# Separate values in a column into multiple columns name and column value

Tags: r, rscript

I would like to split a certain format of data from one column into multiple columns. Below are my sample data:

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,2),data=c('apple:A%1^B%2^C%3_orange:A%1^B%2',
                                   'apple:A%1^B%2^D%3_orange:A%3^B%2'))
#    id    data
#    1    apple:A%1^B%2^C%3_orange:A%1^B%2
#    2    apple:A%1^B%2^D%3_orange:C%3^B%2
```

which will then gives the following output

```
 id   data_apple_A  data_apple_B  data_apple_C  data_apple_D  data_orange_A  data_orange_B
 1       1               2              3                          1              2
 2       1               2                            3            1              2
```

I have been able to do this but the method that I use involves looping through each of the row and perform the str_split by each of the separator in order to get the data for each row and append it to the final output dataframe which is very slow considering I will have 500k rows by 20 input column.

I don't think my for loop is a proper R way to code for this use case. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` with `str_extract`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(zoo)
library(stringr)
dt <- cSplit(df, 'data', "\\^|_", fixed = FALSE, "long")[, c('grp', 'grp2', 'val') 
   := .(na.locf(str_extract(data, "^[A-Za-z]+(?=:)")), 
     str_extract(data, "[A-Z](?=[%])"), as.numeric(str_extract(data, "\\d+")))  ][]
dcast(dt, id ~ paste0("data_", grp) + grp2, value.var = 'val', sep = "_", fill = 0)
#    id data_apple_A data_apple_B data_apple_C data_apple_D data_orange_A data_orange_B
#1:  1            1            2            3            0             1             2
#2:  2            1            2            0            3             3             2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But you can explain a litte on how the na.locf works?

Comment: @kaexch When there are NA values, `na.locf` replace that NA values with the previous non-NA value